# Lock in Skype call screen

Tags: macos, mac, skype

What is the significance of the little lock on the top of a Skype call screen on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this is there to remind users that Skype calls are secured. From [Skype's security FAQ](http://www.skype.com/security/detailed-security/faq/):

> All Skype-to-Skype voice, video, and
>   instant message conversations are
>   encrypted with strong encryption
>   algorithms, and are therefore secure
>   and private during transmission.